# Rename subfolder in multiple folders by replacing a part of the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Assuming I have multiple subfolders inside many different folders (**). All the folders are in a main folder called Project1. I want to replace the string name of the folders using `substring` function.

```
import glob
import os 
import pandas as pd

paths = glob.glob("CC:/Users/xxx/College/Project1/**/", recursive=True)
```

Assuming the subfolders are in multiple folders and have a naming convention as follows:

```
fwjekljfwelj-10-fwefw #(the path for this folder is "CC:/Users/xxx/College/Project1/**/wjekljfwelj-10-fwefw/")
kljkgpjrjrel-11-wwref
fwefjkecmuon-12-cfecd
dsfshncrpout-13-lplce
```

The alphanumeric sequence prior to the - character is meaningless. I want to replace the string preceding the dashed line with the number 20. The new subfolders would thus be:

```
2010-fwefw
2011-wwref
2012-cfecd
2013-lplce
```

I can do it individually for each subfolder using `str.split('-', 1)[-1]` and then append '20' to the name, but I would like to automate the process.
I am renaming folder names, not the files themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) with `topdown=False`:

```
import re
import os

top_dir = 'CC:/Users/xxx/College/Project1'

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(top_dir, topdown=False):
    for dirname in dirnames:
        if re.search(r'-\d{2}-', dirname):
            new_dirname = f"20{dirname.split('-', 1)[1]}"
            new_dirpath = os.path.join(dirpath, new_dirname)
            old_dirpath = os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)
            print(f'{old_dirpath} -> {new_dirpath}')
            os.rename(old_dirpath, new_dirpath)
```

Before:

```
Project1
└── fldr1
    ├── dsfshncrpout-13-lplce
    ├── fwefjkecmuon-12-cfecd
    ├── fwjekljfwelj-10-fwefw
    └── kljkgpjrjrel-11-wwref
```

After:

```
Project1
└── fldr1
    ├── 2010-fwefw
    ├── 2011-wwref
    ├── 2012-cfecd
    └── 2013-lplce
```

Comment: this worked for me, except the first line of the loop has to be modified: for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(base_dir, topdown=False): to for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(top_dir, topdown=False):

Comment: @JodeCharger100. Thanks. `base_dir` was the name of my old variable. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if this works for you:

```
import os
import glob

# define the base folder
base_folder = "CC:/Users/xxx/College/Project1"

# get all the subfolders
subfolders = glob.glob(os.path.join(base_folder, "**/"), recursive=True)

# iterate over the subfolders
for folder_path in subfolders:
    # get the folder name
    folder_name = os.path.basename(folder_path)
    # split the folder name by the "-" character
    parts = folder_name.split("-")
    # construct the new folder name
    new_folder_name = "20" + parts[-1]
    # get the parent folder path
    parent_folder = os.path.dirname(folder_path)
    # construct the new folder path
    new_folder_path = os.path.join(parent_folder, new_folder_name)
    # rename the folder
    os.rename(folder_path, os.path.join(parent_folder, new_folder_path))
```

Comment: threw an error at the last line. OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/Users/xxx/College/Project1/' -> '/Users/xxx/College/Project1/20'

Comment: try again as I edited the answer to construct new folder using parent folder as well.

Comment: I tried it with a few changes but it still shows up the same error

Comment: When I print subfolders, it is showing me "CC:/Users/xxx/College/Project1" and "CC:/Users/xxx/College/Project1/fldr1/" and "CC:/Users/xxx/College/Project1/fldr1/wjekljfwelj-10-fwefw/" plus the others

Comment: Is this the actual path of your system? I mean, didn't you modify it to not reveal the actual username?

Comment: yes, I modified it. if it helps, it is a MacBook. "/Users/xxx/College/Project1"